# Post both to Google Plus Personal and Page?

Tags: google-plus

Is there a way to have posts appear in both your Google Plus (business) Page and personal posts without posting twice?

For example, if I post to my Page stream, I want that post to also show up in my personal stream and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You will have to post twice or post once and reshare that post.